# Post comments with Ctrl/Cmd+Enter

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

It would be good if after typing a comment, the comment could be submitted by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Mac/*nix).

Other sites like Twitter use this keyboard shortcut and I find myself trying to use this on Stack Overflow after typing a comment too.

Comment: Is it not already sent with enter?

Comment: Not sure if something was done or not but at least on my machine enter and ctrl+enter both post a comment

Comment: If <kbd>Enter</kbd> works then I didn’t know about that, sorry. I don’t think it’s grounds for the down-votes this question’s received, though.

Comment: @MartinBean [Down votes are different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). It's not because you wrote a bad question, it's because people disagree with your suggestion, nothing more.

Comment: ... I'm for the Cmd+Enter proposal. It's used absolutely everywhere.
I can verify that `Cmd+Enter` does NOT send the comment.

`Cmd+Enter` makes tonnes of sense! Why not have both `Enter` and `Cmd+Enter` both send the comment?

Answer (score 7):

I don't use Twitter (shock! no way!) but I'd guess the reason why they use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is because <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a valid input as part of the message - which it isn't here in Stack Exchange comments.

So what you're asking for is to remove a feature that works perfectly fine and replace it with a different key sequence simply because some other site does it.

You would also potentially confuse many people who have requested the opposite - that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> be used to insert a line break. I don't mind if they end up confused, but I would mind when they start raising questions about it on Meta.